# is my function correct about SQL injection

Tags: php

for some reasons i can't use PDO so i have created a simple function to clean input data, please view and suggest modification to prevent from SQL and XSS. here is function.

```
function cleanStr($cStr) {
    $cStr = trim($cStr);
    $cStr = htmlspecialchars($cStr);
    $cStr = addslashes($cStr);
    return $cStr; }
```

Comment: What about `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: i am using PHP: 5.6.3, i don't know mysql_real_espac_string is working with it or not

Comment: What database adapter are you using? Your database adapter will have appropriate escaping functions. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid doing this kind of escaping yourself, as it is not always easy to catch all injection possibilities.

If you are using MySQL and cannot use PDO, see if you can make use of the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add more a function to prevent SQL injection

```
$cStr = mysql_real_escape_string($cStr);
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated. Don't use it.